# How to compare zero integer with value

Tags: php

In database, Student_id is containing 0 value. I want to check it in if condition, but required result is not achieved. I have tried following scenarios in if condition:

```
if(is_null($item['student_id'])) {}

if($item['student_id'] === 0){}

if($item['student_id'] == 0){}

if(intval($item['student_id']) == 0){}

if(strval("$item['student_id']") == "0"){}
```

**Note:** Currently Iam trying to print some message in if conditions. But on student_id = 0, nothing is printed. If student_id is other than 0, then print is working fine.

Can some one guide me what Iam doing wrong and how it can be rectified.

I have added var_dump

```
    array
  '_id' => 
    object(MongoId)[2]
      public '$id' => string '50906d7fa3c412bb040eb577' (length=24)
  'student_id' => int 0
  'type' => string 'exam' (length=4)
  'score' => float 54.653543636265
array
  '_id' => 
    object(MongoId)[6]
      public '$id' => string '50906d7fa3c412bb040eb578' (length=24)
  'student_id' => int 0
  'type' => string 'quiz' (length=4)
  'score' => float 31.950044967421
array
  '_id' => 
    object(MongoId)[2]
      public '$id' => string '50906d7fa3c412bb040eb579' (length=24)
  'student_id' => int 0
  'type' => string 'homework' (length=8)
  'score' => float 14.850457681164
```

Comment: if($item['student_id'] > 0){}

Comment: Are you sure there is a value inside `$item['student_id']`? If so, what is that value?

Comment: fyi: the last version is going to issue a warning about using quoted keys in an array within a double-quoted string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work unless your value is not really 0.

```
if(intval($item['student_id']) == 0){}
```

Else another way that could work is this, you almost had it:

```
if($item['student_id'] === '0'){}
```

But then again, make sure you REALLY have a 0 in there... can you var_dump $item for us just to make sure?

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
if((int) $item['student_id'] === 0){
....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if((int)$item['student_id'] === 0){}
```

Answer (score 0):

to compare zero by value , first change the retrieved data to integer, then compare using `===` sign to make sure they are equivalent in both value and type:

```
if(intval($item['student_id']) === 0){}
```